# Pixel font renders incorrectly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, pixel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl3iE.png

Can anyone tell me why this pixel web-font is becoming blurred in Firefox? I'm using @font-face to render it using CSS. The font-size is 8px, which is identical to 50%, and it renders perfectly in Chrome; no blurry artifacts. But in Firefox, every other word is blurry.

EDIT: Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
<style type="text/css">   
@font-face { 
 font-family: 'pokemon_rbyregular';     
 src: url('pokemon_rby-webfont.eot');       
 src: url('pokemon_rby-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('pokemon_rby-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('pokemon_rby-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;   
 font-size: 8px;
 text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
 }
```

This works in every other browser except Firefox (incl. Opera, IE8, and Chrome). I am just wondering if there is some sort of CSS text-rendering setting I could implement that would fix this. I have a feeling it is related to how Firefox implements spacing, as it is only every other word. If I have a long paragraph of jumbled letters, they're all rendered perfectly until I put some spaces in-between them.

Comment: post your actual code, not just an image.

Comment: That image is quite nostalgic, brings back good memories. Also, have you reset the default user agents in the browsers via a CSS reset?

Comment: I think so, although I'm not sure if the reset-min.css is being linked correctly from yahooapis?